# FTP to GCS Transfer

Tags: backup, ftp, sftp, google-cloud-storage

I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to backup files from an (S)FTP Server (Exavault), to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). We are using Exavault a managed FTP service and want to regularly back up files to GCS, then purge files older than 30 days from Exavault.

Current Implementation (Bloody Slow):

1. Mount FTP to filesystem on Google Compute Instance using `curlftpfs`
2. Run `gsutil rsync` to sync files from mounted storage to GCS Bucket
3. Delete files based on mtime +30

This method is running really slow and I don't think it will be a reasonable solution at this point.

Are there any solutions that can do something like this, with ~ 500GB of data, more efficiently?

Comment: Are you using gsutil with the "-m" flag to parallelize it?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: You can try [CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com/) client to see if that improves the speed of the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ftp clients, by mounting each top level directory in the system as a separate curlftpfs. Send to multiple cloud servers if maxing out the bandwidth.

[Offline Media Import.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/offline-media-import-export) Assuming you can get everyone involved to deal with physical media.

Comment: Not a bad idea. I found the issue was doing the rsync directly against curlftpfs, so I just mounted up a fat SSD and did a cp to disk, the gsutil rsync'd from there. Much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a commercial software to accelerate your GCS backups? FileCatalyst Server has an option to mount GCS as a file system. Then you can use any FileCatalyst client application (HotFolder, CLI, Web based) to transfer files to FileCatalyst Server with GCS mounted as a virtual folder.

Here is the product link: https://filecatalyst.com/solutions/filecatalyst-direct/

Yes I work for FileCatalyst.